# Unix elif syntax error

Tags: unix

Getting error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `elif' 
`elif [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "Automation" ] then'
```

I'm saving in Unix line format in Textpad++ so I'm not sure what the problem is...

```
#!/bin/bash

....

if [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "Utility" ] then

    echo "$PROJECT_DIR: Compiling..."
    javac -sourcepath $SOURCE -classpath $CLASSPATH -d $OUTPUT $SOURCE/*.java -deprecation

    echo "$PROJECT_DIR: Compiling..."
    javac -sourcepath $SOURCE -classpath $CLASSPATH -d $OUTPUT $SOURCE/*.java -deprecation

elif [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "Automation" ] then

    echo "$PROJECT_NAME: Compiling..."
    javac -sourcepath $SOURCE -classpath $CLASSPATH -d $OUTPUT $SOURCE/*.java

elif [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "Sync" ] then

    echo "$PROJECT_DIR: Compiling..."
    javac -sourcepath $SOURCE -classpath $CLASSPATH -d $OUTPUT $SOURCE/*.java -deprecation 
    echo "$PROJECT_DIR: Compiling..."
    javac -sourcepath $SOURCE -classpath $CLASSPATH -d $OUTPUT $SOURCE/*.java -deprecation 
    echo "$PROJECT_DIR: Compiling..."
    javac -sourcepath $SOURCE -classpath $CLASSPATH -d $OUTPUT $SOURCE/*.java -deprecation 

fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need a semicolon (or a newline) between the `]` and the `then`.

`[` is not part of the shell's syntax. It's a built-in command, equivalent to the `test` command (except that `[` requires a `]` as its last argument and `test` doesn't).

(On the other hand, the keywords `if`, `then`, `elif`, and `fi` as well as the semicolon, *are* part of the shell's syntax.)

So if you write:

```
if [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "Utility" ] then
```

the word `then` is simply another argument to the `[` command.

Changing each occurrence of `] then` to `] ; then` should fix the problem.

Comment: Okay I actually tried the ; after ]  but I only put it after the 1st ] not all of them.  So I put a ; behind all ] occurences and now it works.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this instead (Removed most of the code lines to keep the answer short). no need of last `elif` condition `elif [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "Sync" ]`. It should just be an `else` part as pointed below.

```
if [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "Utility" ] 
then
    echo "$PROJECT_DIR: Compiling..."    
elif [ "$PROJECT_DIR" = "Automation" ] 
then
    echo "$PROJECT_NAME: Compiling..."    
else 
    echo "$PROJECT_DIR: Compiling..."
fi
```